# Is there a symbols package that has the egyptian symbol djed?

Tags: symbols, unicode, overleaf

I want to use the [djed symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djed)() in my itemize for creative purposes (I am using Overleaf to do this activity). Does anyone know a package or a way to create the symbol?

Comment: If you're using either XeTeX or LuaTeX you could use a font that contains it, according to the great `albatross` utility Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs or Noto Sans EgyptHiero could be used (you can check the fonts on your machine using `albatross 0x132bd` on the command line).

Comment: Download the image, use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and then `\begin{itemize}[label=\includegraphics[height=1ex]{djed}]`...`\end{itemize}`.

Comment: The `hieroglyph` package has the glyph, but for some reason (possibly an unclear licence, but it seems to be GNU General Public License) it is not included in TeX Live. You can find it on CTAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX) you could include a font containing that symbol. Then you could use `enumitem` to change the itemize symbol:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hiero{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
%\newcommand\djed{{\hiero }} % if your editor doesn't like this input use the next line
\newcommand\djed{{\hiero ^^^^^^0132bd}}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\djed]
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

You can use `albatross` to check which font on your system contains the symbol, for that use `albatross 0x132bd` on your command line (`albatross` should be contained in a recent TeX Live/MikTeX installation).

[image]

Comment: I am writing the activity in Overleaf, do you know how can I change it to use LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX)? Found it, just change the compiler in the left menu...

Comment: Overleaf does not accept , it becomes ��. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @Codewraith use `^^^^^^0132bd` instead.

Comment: Nice, using `\newcommand\djed{{\hiero ^^^^^^0132bd}}` worked perfectly. Just the `[label=\djed]` did not work for some reason. So I added it as \item [\djed]. Do you perhaps know why using `[label=\djed]` did not work?

Comment: @Codewraith did you use `\usepackage{enumitem}`? As long as you don't use `beamer` (or other incompatible packages/classes) this should do. If it doesn't ask a new question with a minimal code example reproducing your issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Skillmon, I didn't see the package, using it worked like a charm, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the inspector in my browser displaying your question I see it use U+132BD in font Segoe UI Historic so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\egypt{Segoe UI Historic}
\begin{document}

zzz {\egypt }
\end{document}
```

requires lualatex or xelatex (and windows for the segoe font, but whichever font you need)